# Format date in python as is done in django template

Tags: django

In a django template, datetime is formatted as follows:

```
June 17, 2020, 7:56 p.m.
```

How do I get this same formatting in Python? I think it has something do to with `USE_L10N`

Thanks!!

Comment: The format is culture dependent, so in a different country, it can look different.

Comment: So, is there some way to mimic the way that it is formatted in django tempates but in python?